# AutoMapper: conversion of string into Object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, xsd, automapper

The project I am working on use NHibernate, AutoMapper and Fluent. All I need to do is read the XML file and enter the data into database. But there is a problem I am facing. when I try to map the Source and Destination I get the error which I have mentioned in the title.

Below is my code:

```
public partial class Language
{
    public string languageIdField;
    public string languageNameField;
}

 public partial class Person
        {   
            public int personIdField;  
            public string firstNameField;  
            public string lastNameField;  
            public int stateField;
            public int enableEmailField;
            public int attestPersonLockedField;
            public string emailAddressField;
            public string languageId;
         }
```

I am creating above classes with xsd2code tool.But I have simplified it here.

Model classes are:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress {get; set;}
    .....
    public int state {get; set;}

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Language language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public virtual string LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual string LanguageName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I map them with AutoMapper:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Language, Models.Language>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Models.Person>();
```

And that's how I am reading and trying to save the data:

```
object id = null;
foreach (var item in templateData.Languages)
{
    id = save<Dicom.Expense.Models.Language>(item); // this will return the language id
}

Person person = new Person();
person.Emailaddress = templatedata.Person.EmailAddress;
....
person.languageId = id.ToString();  
save<Dicom.Expense.Models.Person>(person);
private void save<TModel>(object templateObject)
{
   var dbModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TModel>(templateObject);
   repository.Save<object>(dbModel);
}
```

When I try to save the Person information I get the error:

> could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'fkLanguageID

And this is because the Person table have the language ID as a foreign key in it. Now I do not know what changes I need to do so that Person source and destination map properly and save the data into database.

**EDIT:**
I have realized that I need to change the **Person.languageId** value into **PersonModel.Language** object so that NHibernate can read it and map it. Is it possible to use **Customer Resolver or Type Converter** to achieve this?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Models.Person>().ForMember(dest => dest.Language, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());

public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<Person, Models.Language>
    {
        public Dicom.Expense.Models.Language ResolveCore(Person source)
        {
            ?????
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `person.Language.languageId = id.ToString();`?

Comment: I do not think so but what I did now is I am using  `person.Language = new Language { LanguageId = languageID.ToString(), LanguageName = "Svenska"};` but still I get the same error.
Also I made the `languageId as Language language` an instance of Language class inside non-model Person class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a Resolver which AutoMapper provide for complex mapping. While creating a mapping I told the mapper to resolve the Destination Language with Source Language ID by resolving it into an object of type Language.

Below is my code;

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Models.Person>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Language, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new LanguageCodeResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.LanguageId));

public class LanguageCodeResolver : ValueResolver<string, Dicom.Expense.Models.Language>
{
    private IDatabaseLoadRepository loadRepository;
    public LanguageCodeResolver(IDatabaseLoadRepository loadRepository)
    {
        this.loadRepository = loadRepository;
    }
    protected override Models.Language ResolveCore(string languageCode)
    {
        return loadRepository.FindOne<Models.Language>(x => x.LanguageId == languageCode);
    }
}
```